# ag-grid can't move group column when hiding columns

Tags: ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid with group columns. I have problem to manually move group columns when there is a hidden column in one of the groups.

These are the columns definition, the "Athlete" column is hidden:

```
this.columnDefs = [
      {
        headerName: "Athlete Details",
        pinned: null, 
        lockPinned: true,
        marryChildren: true,
        children: [
          {
            headerName: "Athlete",
            field: "athlete",
            width: 150,
            hide: true,
            pinned: null,
            lockPinned: true
          },
          {
            headerName: "Age",
            field: "age",
            width: 90,
            pinned: null,
            lockPinned: true
          },
          {
            headerName: "Country",
            field: "country",
            width: 120,
            pinned: null,
            lockPinned: true
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        headerName: "Sports Results",
        pinned: null, 
        lockPinned: true,
        marryChildren: true,
        children: [
          {
            headerName: "Sport",
            field: "sport",
            width: 110,
            pinned: null,
            lockPinned: true
          },
          {
            headerName: "Total",
            field: "total",
            width: 100,
            pinned: null,
            lockPinned: true
          },
          {
            headerName: "Gold",
            field: "gold",
            width: 100,
            pinned: null,
            lockPinned: true
          },
          {
            headerName: "Silver",
            field: "silver",
            width: 100,
            filter: "agNumberColumnFilter",
            pinned: null,
            lockPinned: true
          },
          {
            headerName: "Bronze",
            field: "bronze",
            width: 100,
            pinned: null,
            lockPinned: true
          }
        ]
      }
```

Here's a plunker demo with full example: https://plnkr.co/edit/jjeDCsswWT0BnPwGGtjU?p=preview

In the example, the Athlete column is hidden.
After dragging the "Athlete Results" group column to the right, it's not possible to drag the "Sports Results" group column to the right.
Once removing the hide = true from the Athlete column it works fine.